# Dataframe horizontal stacked bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am reading the movielens user data. I want to plot the age and occupation grouped by gender (in two separate plots). But I get this error:

`user_df.groupby(['gender'])['age'].unstack().plot.bar()`

AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'unstack' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

I would like the plot to be similar to the example in http://benalexkeen.com/bar-charts-in-matplotlib/
The data format is like :

```
user_id age gender  occupation  zipcode
0   1   24  M   technician  85711
1   2   53  F   other   94043
2   3   23  M   writer  32067
3   4   24  M   technician  43537
4   5   33  F   other   15213
```

Comment: What are your x and y axis for each chart?

Comment: Y-axis is the number of users, X-axis would be the occupation for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
df.groupby(['occupation'])['user_id'].nunique().plot.bar()
```

[image]

For both **gender** and **occupation**, you can do:

```
df.groupby(['occupation','gender'])['user_id'].size().unstack().plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: but i would like to plot 'male' and 'female' side by side